# Can you have fractional branches of the logarithm?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Normally, branches of the logarithm are generalized in the form of $$ln_k(z)=ln(z)+2 \pi i k.$$

However, is there a such a generalization that can be made not just for integer values, but for any value? It seems there should be, and I don't quite see why they don't simply extend it to any number with such a simple looking formula.

All you would really be doing is shifting the phase along the logarithm's Riemann surface. So, take for instance $ln(z)+ \pi i k$. I don't think it would be completely accurate to express it this way, but so you can see what I am saying, can this be expressed as $ln_{1/2}(z)$?

Answer (score 0):

No. The reason behind the $2\pi ik$ lies in the fact the, given $z,w\in\mathbb C$,$$e^z=e^w\iff(\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}):z=w+2\pi ik.$$Thherefore, the only branches that can exist are those that you described.

Comment: I'm not really concerned with $e^{2 \pi i k} = 1$ for any k, I'm looking for a more complex formula that can describe this general principal of branching with respect to different offsets on the Riemann surface. Your statement is only true with respect to the current confines of how branches are chosen to be defined, but what I am asking about is to go beyond the current definition to extend to any constant, not just integers k. It seems exceptionally possible to do this, well within the current scope of mathematics.